# Bounding the number of ways to express $n = \prod_{i=1}^k[d_i,e_i]$? ($[\cdot, \cdot]$ is the lcm)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

In the paper I am reading it says that the number of 
$d_1, ..., d_k, e_1, ..., e_k \in \mathbb{N}$ to express a square-free $n$ as
$$
n = \prod_{i=1}^k[d_i,e_i], 
$$
by this I mean #$ \{ (d_1, ..., d_k, e_1, ..., e_k) \in \mathbb{N}^{2k} :   n = \prod_{i=1}^k [d_i,e_i] \}$, 
is less than or equal to $\tau_{3k}(n)$ (number of ways to express $n$ as a product of $3k$ natural numbers). 
I would appreciate if someone could explain this to me. Thank you.

Comment: There are a couple of things not clear to me. When you say the "... the number of ...", are you referring to $k$, the number of unique ordered pairs of $(d_i,e_i)$, or something else? Also, when you say "is bounded by ...", is this bounded below or above? Thanks, in advance, for clarifying this (preferably by updating your question text).

Comment: The question has been updated to make it clearer. I hope it is clear now. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$f_k(n) =\# \{ (d,e) \in \Bbb{Z}_{\ge 1}^k, n = \prod_{i=1}^k lcm(d_i,e_i)\}$$
With $g_i = \gcd(d_i,e_i),  D_i = \frac{d_i}{g_i},E_i = \frac{e_i}{g_i},\gcd(D_i,E_i)=1,lcm(d_i,e_i)= D_iE_ig_i$ it is
$$f_k(n) =\# \{ (D,E,g)\in \Bbb{Z}_{\ge 1}^k, n = \prod_{i=1}^k D_iE_ig_i, gcd(D_i,E_i)=1\}$$
$$ \le \# \{ (D,E,g)\in \Bbb{Z}_{\ge 1}^k, n = \prod_{i=1}^k D_iE_ig_i\}$$
$$ = \# \{ a \in \Bbb{Z}_{\ge 1}^{3k}, n = \prod_{j=1}^{3k} a_j\}$$